# NetLogo GIS extension with imported ASCII data: "math operation produced a non-number"

Tags: ascii, gis, netlogo

I'm getting this error when I try to run my NetLogo model:
math operation produced a non-number

Additionally, I'm noticing a problem on the interface side. Even though I don't get an error during setup, all of the patches are blue when at least some of them should be green.

I'm wondering if these two problems mean I've made a mistake when importing my ASCII files.

This is the metadata for each of my ASCII files. Values range from 0-5. There are no NAs.

```
NCOLS 125 
NROWS 82 
XLLCORNER -844919.541237088 
YLLCORNER 2451362.63607842 
CELLSIZE 33565.7176106285 
NODATA_value -9999
```

Here is my NetLogo code.

```
breed[persons person]
breed[trails trail]

extensions [
  gis
]

globals [
  competition-value
  land.or.sea-dataset
  cost-dataset
  motivation-dataset
  boundary-dataset
]

patches-own [
  land.or.sea
  cost
  motivation
  boundary
  difference
  times.here
]

to setup-gis
  set land.or.sea-dataset gis:load-dataset "environmentLSL_1.asc"
  set cost-dataset gis:load-dataset "environmentLSL_2.asc"
  set motivation-dataset gis:load-dataset "environmentLSL_3.asc"
  set boundary-dataset gis:load-dataset "environmentLSL_4.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of land.or.sea-dataset)
                                                (gis:envelope-of cost-dataset)
                                                (gis:envelope-of motivation-dataset)
                                                (gis:envelope-of boundary-dataset))
end

to set-patch-values
ask patches[
  set land.or.sea gis:raster-sample land.or.sea-dataset gis:world-envelope
  set cost gis:raster-sample cost-dataset gis:world-envelope
  set motivation gis:raster-sample motivation-dataset gis:world-envelope
  set boundary gis:raster-sample boundary-dataset gis:world-envelope
]
end

to setup
  clear-all
  create-persons 100
  set-default-shape persons "person"
  set-default-shape trails "dot"
  ask patches [
    setup-gis
    ifelse land.or.sea = 1
      [set pcolor green]
      [set pcolor blue]
    set competition-value persons-here
  ]
  set-patch-values
  ask persons [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
  ]
  reset-ticks
end


to go
  if ticks >= 1000
    [stop]
  if ((count persons) < 100)
    [replace-persons]
  ifelse competition
    [move-persons-with-competition]
    [move-persons]
  remove-persons
  ask patches [
    if count persons-here > 0 [set times.here (times.here + 1)]
  ]
  tick
end

to replace-persons
  create-persons (100 - (count persons))
  set-default-shape persons "person"
  ask persons [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
  ]
end

to move-persons-with-competition
  if competition-value < max-persons-per-cell [
    ask patches [
      set motivation (motivation * motivation.coefficient)
      set cost (cost * cost.coefficient)
      set difference (motivation - cost)
         ask persons-here [
            uphill4 difference
          ]
        ]
     ]
   ask persons[
    hatch-trails 1 [set color 16]
  ]
end

to move-persons
  ask patches [
    set motivation (motivation * motivation.coefficient)
    set cost(cost * cost.coefficient)
    set difference (motivation - cost)
     ask persons-here [
        uphill4 difference
      ]
    ]
  ask persons[
    hatch-trails 1 [set color 16]
  ]
end

to remove-persons
  ask persons [
    if boundary = 1
      [die]
  ]
end

to export-results
  set times.here gis:patch-dataset times.here
  gis:store-dataset times.here "times.here.asc"
end
```

Comment: Hi Bailey- I get a NaN problem sometimes when my .asc files don't cover the entirety of the netlogo world once applied and then I try to use them for calculations. However, if your files all have the same metadata I don't think that's what's happening- have you tried using `apply-raster` instead of `raster-sample` in your `set-patch-values` procedure? Also, are you using Netlogo 5.3 or 6?